# Why am I unable to go to admin content in one of my websites?

Tags: 7, navigation

I am unable to go to admin content in (one of my websites using) Drupal 7

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLFP7o0omuM

What would cause this?

I am unable to access any admin pages in Drupal 7. And this happened after I uploaded all the files from backup and I asked the internet hosting company to do a database restore to a back up a month ago when the web site was working fine.

Comment: Did you try something like "www.arguemax.com/_drupal-7.26" does it work? Or maybe "www.arguemax.com/_drupal-7.26?q=user" ?? And also I see an error 500, it means bad code, can you ask your hosting for the error log?

Comment: Are the versions of SQL database when you backed up and restored the same? If they are different, the database contents may need an update?